# ComboBox tooltip is not displayed

Tags: wpf, combobox, tooltip, datatemplate

I am trying following code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" ToolTip="This will never be shown, why?" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Then I assign some `ItemSource` in code behind, select item and trying to mouseover combobox. The result - no tooltip.

If I do same with `ListBox` - tooltip is shown for each item. If I open `ComboBox` popup - tooltip is shown for each item.

If I snoop it:

[image]

Then there is no `CheckBox` in visual tree. But content presenter displays it. What is going on?

Of course I can additionally bind `ComboBox.Tooltip` to e.g. its `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex.ToolTip`, but it will not work always and depends on content and `ComboBox` configuration: is it collection of `ComboBoxItems` or maybe `ItemsSource`, is it using `ValuePath` or not, etc.

I want to understand why there is not `CheckBox`. And I want tooltip from datatemplate to be shown.

---

It might be a bug of `Snoop` or something else, but after opening and closing `ComboBox` popup and hitting refresh button in `Snoop` it finally shows `CheckBox`:

[image]

But then my question still: Why tooltip is not shown? I can see it is there, but mouseovering `ComboBox` doesn't display anything.

Comment: Since an element can only appear once in the element tree, the `ComboBox` creates a visual copy of the `CheckBox` using a `VisualBrush` and then displays the clone in the selection box: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,896

Comment: @mm8, aha, and I am guessing it only uses real `CheckBox` when it's just selected or when editing. So there will be no tooltip sadly.

Comment: Yes, the `Rectangle` that hosts the `VisualBrush` has no `Tooltip`.

Comment: @mm8, thanks, that answers my question. So I must deal with `ComboBox.Tooltip` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why tooltip is not shown?

Since an element can only appear once in the element tree, the `ComboBox` creates a visual copy of the `CheckBox` using a `VisualBrush` and then displays the clone in the selection box: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,896

And the `Rectangle` that hosts the `VisualBrush` has no `Tooltip`.